# MySQL command line interface aliases

Tags: mysql

I am using some commands on mysql client numerous no of times. i want to work smartly with less usage of keyboard. Is there any way to create aliases for mostly used commands like 'show slave status\G','show databases;', 'show tables;' on mysql client just like aliases in bash. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a stored procedure and calling it.

create procedure s() show slave status\G

call s()\G

Answer (score 0):

Do what I do.  Build PHP web pages with the common stuff.  And have each page do more than the basic.  Don't just `show tables`, but do `show table status` and lay it out in a readable table.  And maybe sum up the columns.  And show the Stored Routines.  The cost of a dozen queries to build such a page saves more keystrokes than you concept of aliases.  And it is fast enough to not be a problem if you rarely look at most of the stuff on the page.

The `show databases` page can have the names hyperlinked to your `show table stuff` page.  That turns a bunch of keystrokes into a single link.

If you are looking at a table, and you know which columns are "normalized", then automatically do the JOIN to turn ids into values.

For `show create table`, also do `show indexes` and look into `innodb_table_stats`.  Etc.  The Partition info is hidden away; grab it automatically.

For `show slave status`, have it connect to the Master, too.  And all the Slaves.  And format it so that you can see their states side by side.  Etc.

Comment: Thanks. But we are not allowed to use any php or other web client  except mysql command line interface.

Comment: My condolences.  What kind of management came up with that?

Comment: I have tried like this. mysql> create procedure test()
    -> show slave status\G
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec).   but call test.test() giving results in horizontal format even though i mentioned \G , which should produce the result in vertical format. any idea to get the results in vertical format.

Comment: Try the `\G` on the call.